# How play sound in java without plugins

Tags: java, java-3d

I was reading into java3d and other java library's, and found many classes that are named in a way you could assume that they are used to have sound, however I have yet to find any tutorials on it and every experiment I have tried has failed. How does one go about in using these classes?

javax.media.j3d.AudioDevice;
javax.media.j3d.Sound;
 and so on and so forth.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;

import com.sun.j3d.audioengines.javasound.JavaSoundMixer;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.behaviors.keyboard.KeyNavigatorBehavior;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Box;


public class JavaSound extends Frame implements ActionListener
 {
protected Canvas3D myCanvas3D = new Canvas3D(null);

/** The exit button to quit the application */

protected Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");

/** The button to switch on and off the first sound */

protected Button sound1Button = new Button("Sound 1");

/** The button to switch on and off the second sound */

protected Button sound2Button = new Button("Sound 2");

protected BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 10000.0);
// Create the two point sounds

PointSound sound1 = new PointSound();

PointSound sound2 = new PointSound();



/**
 * Build the view branch of the scene graph. In this case a key navigation
 * utility object is created and associated with the view transform so that
 * the view can be changed via the keyboard.
 * @return BranchGroup that is the root of the view branch
 */
protected BranchGroup buildViewBranch(Canvas3D c)
{
    BranchGroup viewBranch = new BranchGroup();

    Transform3D viewXfm = new Transform3D();

    viewXfm.set(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f));

    TransformGroup viewXfmGroup = new TransformGroup(viewXfm);

    viewXfmGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);

    viewXfmGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);

    ViewPlatform myViewPlatform = new ViewPlatform();

    BoundingSphere movingBounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);
    BoundingLeaf boundLeaf = new BoundingLeaf(movingBounds);

    PhysicalBody myBody = new PhysicalBody();

    PhysicalEnvironment myEnvironment = new PhysicalEnvironment();

    viewXfmGroup.addChild(myViewPlatform);

    viewBranch.addChild(viewXfmGroup);

    View myView = new View();

    myView.addCanvas3D(c);

    myView.attachViewPlatform(myViewPlatform);

    myView.setPhysicalBody(myBody);

    myView.setPhysicalEnvironment(myEnvironment);

    KeyNavigatorBehavior keyNav = new KeyNavigatorBehavior(viewXfmGroup);

    keyNav.setSchedulingBounds(movingBounds);

    viewBranch.addChild(keyNav);

    // Create a sounds mixer to use our sounds with

    // and initialise it

    JavaSoundMixer myMixer = new JavaSoundMixer(myEnvironment);

    myMixer.initialize();

    return viewBranch;

}



protected void addLights(BranchGroup b)
{
    Color3f ambLightColour = new Color3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    AmbientLight ambLight = new AmbientLight(ambLightColour);
    ambLight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    Color3f dirLightColour = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector3f dirLightDir = new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    DirectionalLight dirLight = new DirectionalLight(dirLightColour, dirLightDir);
    dirLight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    b.addChild(ambLight);
    b.addChild(dirLight);
}



protected void addBackgroundSound(BranchGroup b, String soundFile)
{
    // Create a media container to load the file
    MediaContainer droneContainer = new MediaContainer(soundFile);
    // Create the background sound from the media container
    BackgroundSound drone = new BackgroundSound(droneContainer, 1.0f);
    // Activate the sound
    drone.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    drone.setEnable(true);
    // Set the sound to loop forever
    drone.setLoop(BackgroundSound.INFINITE_LOOPS);
    // Add it to the group
    b.addChild(drone);
}



protected void addObjectSound(TransformGroup tg, PointSound sound, String soundFile, float edge)
{
    // First we get the current transform so that we can
    // position the sound in the same place
    Transform3D objXfm = new Transform3D();
    Vector3f objPosition = new Vector3f();
    tg.getTransform(objXfm);
    objXfm.get(objPosition);
    // Create the media container to load the sound
    MediaContainer soundContainer = new MediaContainer(soundFile);
    // Use the loaded data in the sound
    sound.setSoundData(soundContainer);
    sound.setInitialGain(1.0f);
    // Set the position to that of the given transform
    sound.setPosition(new Point3f(objPosition));
    // Allow use to switch the sound on and off
    sound.setCapability(PointSound.ALLOW_ENABLE_READ);
    sound.setCapability(PointSound.ALLOW_ENABLE_WRITE);
    sound.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    // Set it off to start with
    sound.setEnable(false);
    // Set it to loop forever
    sound.setLoop(BackgroundSound.INFINITE_LOOPS);
    // Use the edge value to set to extent of the sound
    Point2f[] attenuation = { new Point2f(0.0f, 1.0f), new Point2f(edge, 0.1f) };
    sound.setDistanceGain(attenuation);
    // Add the sound to the transform group
    tg.addChild(sound);
}



protected BranchGroup buildContentBranch()
{
    // Create the appearance
    Appearance app = new Appearance();
    Color3f ambientColour = new Color3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Color3f emissiveColour = new Color3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Color3f specularColour = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Color3f diffuseColour = new Color3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float shininess = 20.0f;
    app.setMaterial(new Material(ambientColour, emissiveColour, diffuseColour, specularColour, shininess));
    // Make the cube
    Box myCube = new Box(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, app);
    TransformGroup cubeGroup = new TransformGroup();
    BranchGroup contentBranch = new BranchGroup();
    addLights(contentBranch);
    addObjectSound(cubeGroup, sound1, new String("C:\\Users\\Sawyera\\Desktop\\loop1.wav"), 10.0f);
    addObjectSound(cubeGroup, sound2, new String("C:\\Users\\Sawyera\\Desktop\\loop2.wav"), 20.0f);
    addBackgroundSound(contentBranch, new         String("C:\\Users\\Sawyera\\Desktop\\loop3.wav"));
    cubeGroup.addChild(myCube);
    contentBranch.addChild(cubeGroup);
    return contentBranch;
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == exitButton)
    {
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == sound1Button)
    {
        if (sound1.getEnable())
            sound1.setEnable(false);
        else
            sound1.setEnable(true);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == sound2Button)
    {
        sound2.setEnable(!sound2.getEnable());
    }
}



public JavaSound()
{
    VirtualUniverse myUniverse = new VirtualUniverse();
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(myUniverse);
    // buildUniverse(myCanvas3D);
    myLocale.addBranchGraph(buildContentBranch());
    myLocale.addBranchGraph(buildViewBranch(myCanvas3D));
    setTitle("SimpleSounds");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Panel bottom = new Panel();
    bottom.add(sound1Button);
    bottom.add(sound2Button);
    bottom.add(exitButton);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myCanvas3D);
    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottom);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    sound1Button.addActionListener(this);
    sound2Button.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JavaSound sw = new JavaSound();
}
}
```

Comment: you have to reformat you're code to get an answer it's not a readable   code

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? or tried to figure out why there is Null Pointer Exception thrown at line 963 of Canvas3D.java. It looks like you are missing some config param. Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Thank you Clark. I changed the original code i got off the web that defined the file paths to my desktop for the sound instead of using                                                              addObjectSound(cubeGroup, sound1, new String("file:./loop1.wav"), 10.0f);
    addObjectSound(cubeGroup, sound2, new String("file:./loop2.wav"), 20.0f);
    addBackgroundSound(contentBranch, new String("file:./loop3.wav"));

Comment: Deleting the code from the original question makes my answer look stupid because it removes the actual problem he was having...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Javadoc:

"graphicsConfiguration - a valid GraphicsConfiguration object that will be used to create the canvas. **This object should not be null**..." [javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html#Canvas3D%28java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29)

You initalise it as null:

```
protected Canvas3D myCanvas3D = new Canvas3D(null);
```

Here's the initialisation used in a tutorial:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config);
```